# Why do some sites not configure their servers to get a SSLabs A rating?

Tags: tls

As the title suggests, I am wondering why some sites do not configure their servers to get a SSLabs A rating.

I have found a [link](https://zurgl.com/nginx-how-to-get-an-a-or-a-rating-on-securityheaders-io/) suggesting why an A+ rating could complicate things compared to an A rating, but no other information. I also do not think that it is because of backward compatibility with older browsers such as IE 11 or Safari 8 (because those implement TLS1.2 and some ciphers with Forward Secrecy, meaning support of these browsers should be possible with an A rating).

Comment: "Why don't people make more secure decisions?" is a type of question that is ultimately unanswerable. There are a hundred different reasons why a site might not choose to go through this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of it is definitely backward compatibility. While IE11 on Win10 is capable of TLS 1.2 by default, some older versions of IE had TLS 1.2 disabled by default or were outright incapable of it, and some sites target older versions. There's also things like old versions of Android or other mobile browsers, embedded systems with older firmware, and so on.

Some of it is hardware cost. TLS-terminating load balancers used to be (maybe still are?) a common hardware purchase for somebody building a data center or similar large Internet-connected network, and many of those had limited configurability / upgradability and hence might not fully support modern protocols or be unable to turn old ones off. They could be replaced, but are a substantial monetary investment.

Some of it is lack of concern. Lots of sites use TLS less because the security properties are relevant, and more because of the various initiatives to get everybody using it (e.g. Google has talked about prioritizing sites that use it in search results, though I don't know if that ever went ahead). Sites that just host static content, or otherwise have no need for communication security, are unlikely to bother configuring for maximum security. They'll probably just use the defaults, which - on many, many platforms / frameworks - will still not get an A rating, especially using older versions.

Some of it is ignorance. While a combination of general efforts of security experts and some highly-publicized exploits in older versions have generally made people aware of the need to configure for higher security (and of scanners like SSLlabs SSLtest), this industry is enormous and most companies (much less individuals) don't have any security engineering talent on staff. They quite possibly have never even considered the question of what protocols, ciphers, and options to configure on their server.

Some of it is sites' hosting not being under the control of the site's owner. Lots of individuals and small companies use hosting providers rather than maintain their own servers. These hosting providers do not always keep up with the times, in terms of secure TLS configurations. This is deeply unfortunate, since they're in an *excellent* position to improve lots of sites at once (and since there's a sense in which their entire reason for existing is "we manage your servers" and thus they're arguably not doing their jobs), but it happens.

Some of it is standards marching on and leaving people behind. Lots of configurations that would previously get "A" ratings, and maybe even "A+" ratings, no longer do. Sites that don't keep up may have historically been considered fully secure and then fallen behind when, e.g., TLS 1.1 was deprecated.

Some of it is people having other priorities. Reconfiguring one TLS server isn't that big of an effort once you know how, but a company might not have anybody who really knows how, or might have a huge fleet of servers that would need this done and don't want to take the risk of breaking something, or might have a task to get around to it but it's de-prioritized below 14 months of work. They're not necessarily wrong, either; while there are known exploits for some old configurations, some were deprecated more out of an abundance of caution than due to any known practical attack. Even things thought of as definitely insecure in general, like RC4 or SSL3.0 with CBC, aren't even necessarily vulnerabilities if the only clients intended to communicate with the servers are ones that interact in ways that RC4 biases or POODLE can't be exploited.

Some of it is just not caring. People make bad security decisions all the times, from the individuals who re-use passwords across sites to the enterprise companies who take months to install patches against vulnerabilities being exploited in the wild. The costs of not having an "A" rating are pretty low - most people will never know, and TLS attacks appear to be (so far, and leaving aside things like Heartbleed) super-rare. In a world where phishing is rampant and shockingly successful, why would anybody bother with attacks that require a MitM position, script injection on another site, and then submitting huge numbers of requests just to get one victim's session token? Personally I think that's a bad mindset to have, but again, we're talking about the kind of people who know using a password of their company name in mixed upper and lower case isn't actually that secure but just don't care because who is going to bother trying to brute-force it? and that's way lower-hanging fruit than disabling RSA key exchange.

Comment: `[Hosting providers]'re in an excellent position to improve lots of sites at once`. Agreed but look it the other way, they are in the worst customer-facing position. Not just they will save money whenever they can, but what about when the owner of a small kebap/pizza shop will call in "I can't access my own site with my own [old] phone"? The conversation will become awkward as the customer support will try to convince the baker that they need more security, but a baker has basically no computer security culture to understand, and just want to sell their bakery. Hence ignorance!!!